# Why did my linked object change shape after making proxy?

Tags: linked-data, proxies

[image]After linking each object in a collection I have two objects that once I make proxy they changed into long shapes nothing like their actual shape!  All the others proxied fine.

Comment: This issue is in Blender 2.8